# XCode base_convert

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I am developing iOS application and I need base_convert function. Application is communicating with PHP server using base_convert, too. In PHP I use this:

```
base_convert($something,16,36) and base_convert($something,36,16)
```

I search for something like I use in PHP, but for Xcode (iOS application).
Thank you.

Comment: Base 16 is obviously Hex, but what sort of number representation uses base 36?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a C++ implementation here:

http://thinkdiff.net/mixed/base-conversion-handle-upto-36-bases/

that will convert back and forth with bases up to 36. Not sure if you need more than that.

Comment: it could probably be easily extended to support whatever base you want, but you will have to come up with the characters to represent the values you are interested in. I think the author stopped with 36 because that much was obvious.

Comment: How can I use it? Can you give me some example usage and what function should I use for base_convert($something,16,36) and what function should I use for base_convert($something,36,16) ?

Comment: The code I linked to requires you do 2 conversion, one from your starting base to decimal, then from decimal to the ending base, so the code would look like: __int base10 = otherToDecimal(string, 16); String base36 = decimalToOther(base10, 36);__

Comment: and finally a wrapper function could be written quickly to encapsulate those two lines (ignore prior C# remark...lost my place for a minute)

Answer (score 0):

There is a complete wikepedia page devoted to [Base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) with various forms of source code that you could adapt (for example the C code should just drop straight in with no modification  but is soooo not objective-c)

There is also [how to convert Decimal to base36](http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/42873-how-to-convert-decimal-to-base36.html) which only does a one-way conversion, but the code is objective-c, so you could get an idea on how to adapt the wikepedia code.

As to why base 36 I learnt:

> Base 36 is therefore the most compact case-insensitive alphanumeric
>   numeral system using ASCII characters

Answer (score 0):

Adapted the code David Hope suggested into Objective-C, here:

https://gist.github.com/furkanmustafa/5660086