# Base36 string to NSData or Hex string

Tags: ios, hex, nsdata, base36

I hava a Base36 String like

```
NSString *base36Str =  "DMSXXHETZEJIIBZ6Z99XNJENPXZK8E9UU8KPJ42B93GAHS4D0HTTMMYCTN3G1GPZYS0H4DOPUX8BA2W7GASGJCIPBDE0XLULGRNUVYRW1N7NYEF777HNSU8RWLZTMNMH2OJ2IWSZFDQNBG6ZBTPMNTIZI4I5H4J5TSI6323M9WOX0FJXKHA7W4HOP3TP0ME6BAH5GD9PTEQEG9A3X25VO3JEFXYHAAU6Q9XFADMFEOMSTZQOU0MMZ0X6EIP";
```

And I want to get a Hex string or NSData from this base36Str, I already tried
https://gist.github.com/furkanmustafa/5660086,but failed.

I'm almost crazy!
Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613548/xcode-base-convert

Comment: Did you try the answer here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14613548/xcode-base-convert

Comment: I tried that, but the result is int type, my base36Str is so large that program was overfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had solved the problem in the simplest possible way.
http://www.santsys.com/code/display?folder=Objective-C&file=BigInt.h

Thanks everybody!